# R dynamic stop word list with terms of frequency one

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, stop-words

I am working on a text mining assignment and am stuck at the moment. The following is based on `Zhaos Text Mining` with Twitter. I cannot get it to work, maybe one of you has a good idea?

**Goal:** I would like to remove all terms from the corpus with a word count of one instead of using a stopword list.

**What I did so far:** I have downloaded the tweets and converted them into a data frame.

```
tf1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets.df$text))


tf1 <- tm_map(tf1, content_transformer(tolower))


removeUser <- function(x) gsub("@[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
tf1 <- tm_map(tf1, content_transformer(removeUser))


removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*", "", x)
tf1 <- tm_map(tf1, content_transformer(removeNumPunct))


removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
tf1 <- tm_map(tf1, content_transformer(removeURL))

tf1 <- tm_map(tf1, stripWhitespace)


#Using TermDocMatrix in order to find terms with count 1, dont know any other way
tdmtf1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(tf1, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))

ones <- findFreqTerms(tdmtf1, lowfreq = 1, highfreq = 1)

tf1Copy <- tf1

tf1List <- setdiff(tf1Copy, ones)


tf1CList <- paste(unlist(tf1List),sep="", collapse=" ")

tf1Copy <- tm_map(tf1Copy, removeWords, tf1CList)

tdmtf1Test <- TermDocumentMatrix(tf1Copy, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))

#Just to test success...
ones2 <- findFreqTerms(tdmtf1Test, lowfreq = 1, highfreq = 1)
(ones2)
```

**The Error:**

> Error in gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\b(%s)\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :   invalid regular expression '(*UCP)\b(senior data scientist global strategy firm 
>   25.0010230541229 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 1 en kdnuggets poll primary programming language for analytics data mining data scienc 
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 2 en iapa canberra seminar mining the internet of everything official statistics in the information age anu june 
>  25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 3 en handling and processing strings in r an ebook in pdf format pages
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 4 en webinar getting your data into r by hadley wickham am edt june th 
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 5 en  before loading the rdmtweets dataset please run librarytwitter to load required package 
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 6 en an infographic on sas vs r vs python datascience via  
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 7 en r is again the kdnuggets poll on top analytics data mining science software 
>   25.0020229816437 48 17 6 6 115 1 186 0 8 en i will run

**In Addition:**

> Warning message: In gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\b(%s)\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :   PCRE pattern compilation error
>           'regular expression is too large'
>           at ''

PS sorry for the bad format at the end could not get it fixed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a reproducible example as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way how to remove all terms from the corpus with a word count of one:

```
library(tm)
mytweets <- c("This is a doc", "This is another doc")

corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(mytweets))
inspect(corp)
# [[1]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# This is a doc
# 
# [[2]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
#   This is another doc
##            ^^^ 

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
inspect(dtm)
# Terms
# Docs another doc this
# 1       0   1    1
# 2       1   1    1

(stopwords <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 1, 1))
# [1] "another"

corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords)
inspect(corp)
# [[1]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# This is a doc
# 
# [[2]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# This is  doc
##        ^ 'another' is gone
```

*(As a side note: The token 'a' from 'This is a...' is gone, too, because `DocumentTermMatrix` cuts out tokens with a length < 3 by default.)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler method using the `dfm()` and `trim()` functions from the [quanteda](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda) package:

```
require(quanteda)

mydfm <- dfm(c("This is a doc", "This is another doc"), verbose = FALSE)
mydfm
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 5 features.
## 2 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
## features
## docs    a another doc is this
## text1 1       0   1  1    1
## text2 0       1   1  1    1

trim(mydfm, minCount = 2)
## Features occurring less than 2 times: 2 
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 3 features.
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
## features
## docs    doc is this
## text1   1  1    1
## text2   1  1    1
```